# How does tikzexternalize work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

tikzexternalize seems to respect local definitions. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={red}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

draws the square in red as expected. How does tikzexternalize do that? If I look at the output, I see

```
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "...-figure0" "\def\tikzex
ternalrealjob{...}\input{...}"' ========
```

where `...` is the name of my tex file. So latex seems to be called on the very same file, and then some magic seems to ensure that latex outputs only the picture in question. But does it have to process all code before that? I guess yes, but that goes much faster than actually compiling all the pages before the picture appears.

Can someone clarify this?

*Edit:* Is the mechanism by which tikzexternaize achieves this hard to understand? Is it possible, for instance, to define an environment `myexternalize` that does the same as tikzexternalize for `tikzpicture`, but for general content?

Comment: Yes, it starts a compilation process of the same file but then the library skips the *output* of everything but that indidvidual TikZ picture. So all previous settings (including for example font settings) are applied when a picture is externalized. But only *when* the pictures is externalized. If you now change `red` to `blue`, the library only checks whether the content of the `tikzpicture` environment has changed and will not externalize it again with a blue drawing. (Unless the process is forced to do so.) This is covered by the [manual](https://tikz.dev/library-external#sec-52.4).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Good to point to the manual. Do you know how tikzexternalize does this? Like, how does it make latex not shipout anything but only produce that one figure?

Answer (score 2):

Qrrbrbirlbel's comment explained what is going on correctly.
To demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \ShellEscape{sleep 5s}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={red}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Save into `a.tex`, delete all auxiliary files (including `a-figure0.pdf` etc.), then `pdflatex -shell-escape a.tex`.

This takes approximately 5 seconds to compile, and subsequent compilations take approximately 0 seconds.
Which means the 5s sleep is not processed when the second image is processed.

On the other hand if it's moved outside...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \ShellEscape{sleep 5s}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={red}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This takes approximately 15 seconds, and if all figures are already generated then it takes approximately 5 seconds.

Anyway, the key point is that the speed-up is made by skipping through the body of `tikzpicture` environments,
and this can be controlled because it's TikZ's environments.
No magic is needed.

On the other hand, this means other environments e.g. `tabular` are not skipped through. You can try it yourself.